# searching a list in a dictionary as keys

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, search, lambda

I was trying to find list of keys in a dictionary using lambda

**input**

```
3
qwe 123
asd 456
zxc 789
qwe
ghj
zxc
```

**output**

```
qwe = 123
Not Found
zxc = 789
```

code is as followed:

```
d = {}
n = int(input())

d = dict((input().lower()).split() for _ in range(n))
List = d.keys()

L = []

for _ in range (n):
    name = (input().strip()).lower()

    L.append(name)

output = map(lambda x,y :x if x in y else False,List,L)

result = list(output)

for i in result:
    if i !=False:
        print('{}={}'.format(i,d[i]))
    else:
        print("Not Found")
```

not getting any Output.Can anyone help

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to append to a list abc on line number 12 which you haven't defined yet. Replacing abc with L fixes your code.

Comment: hey,Thanks for pointing that out. Corrected that..now the code is working only for small number of cases....for larger inputs like 1000 its not working

Comment: you should replace your map line with `output = map((lambda y :y if y in List else False),L)` . Since in the current one both x and y in the lambda func are strings instead of x being a string and y being a list.